# SQL how can i get sum,avg and count of my table?

Tags: sql

I have a table with 3 columns: name,continent and population. I need to make a new table with the sum of countries, avg of population , and sum of population.

this is my code but i get an error

```
SELECT COUNT(name) AS number,
AVG(population) AS average, 
SUM(population) AS total FROM coutries;
```

this is my error

```
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 99: Table 'ri_db.coutries' doesn't exist
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: You don't have a column countries, so use COUNT(name).

Comment: You probably intend `ri_db.countries`.

Comment: Try the answer by @forpas

Comment: @Dave I just changed it , I still get an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table's name is `countries` and there is no column countries, so do this:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS number,
  AVG(population) AS average, 
  SUM(population) AS total 
FROM countries;
```

Answer (score 1):

"from coutries" should probably be "from countries".

And as mentioned in a comment use "count(*)".

Answer (score 0):

"I have a table with 3 columns: name,continent and population."

Then if you want the total count of rows, you need COUNT(1) or COUNT(*). COUNT(countries) will not work: there is no column called 'countries'.